# Which way to use a django formset

Tags: django, django-forms

Lets say I have a `Person` model as well as a `Event` model.

Event has a `ManyToMany` relationship with Person

```
class Event(models.Model):
    canceled_persons = models.ManyToManyField('Person', related_name='canceled')
    confirmed_persons = models.ManyToManyField('Person', related_name='confirmed')
    no_response = models.ManyToManyField('Person', related_name='no_response')
```

When an event is created it sends out a email to a group of selected people with links for them to click to update their status. By default they are all listed in "no_response". Aside from updating via email, they can call in and the contact rep can update their status.

My question is how should I go about setting up a form to make this possible to update multiple at once. My first idea was to have a form with each one of these donors and have radio buttons next to their names for `canceled, confirmed, no_response` and a save button at the bottom

Should I be using a modelformset_factory from Person or should it be from Event? Or am I overlooking someething that is easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have designed the models slightly differently. The `Event` model should contain the details of the event. A separate class say 'Booking' should handle the relationship between `Person` and the `Event`. This way you can manage the states better and don't have to manage several Many-To-Many relatioships. For e.g.

```
class Event(model.Models):
    name = model.CharField(max_length=100)


class Booking(model.Models):
    BOOKING_STATES = (
        ("CAN", "Cancelled"),
        ("CON", "Confrimed"),
        ("NOR", "No Response"),
    )
    event = model.ForeignKey(Event)
    person = model.ForeignKey(Person)
    booking_status = model.CharField(max_length=3, choices=BOOKING_STATES)
```

This makes it easy to build a formset as well.